# how to see files in repository before running 'update'

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I run `hg pull` which added new changes to my repository. Before updating my working directory with the new changes i would like to see these new files/changes. I believe in SVN i used `svn st -u` but how is it done in Mercurial?

Comment: `hg push` adds new changes to your repository?  Do you mean it adds changes to the remote repository?

Comment: Thank you Robert...i did wrote it wrong and now corrected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(After pulling the changes via `hg pull`) you can run `hg status --rev tip` to show an output similar to `svn st -u`.

Answer (score 15):

Before you even pull you can use:

```
hg incoming --stat
```

to see a summary of changes or

```
hg incoming --patch
```

to see the actual deltas.

After pulling (but before updating!) you can do:

```
hg status --rev tip
```

to see a list of the changed files, or

```
hg diff --rev tip
```

to see a summary of the changes, or

```
hg diff -r tip
```

to see the combined diff.

Comment: Thank you Ry4an...your answer was what i was asking but Michael answered it first,so i am giving Michael...thank though...from your answer i learnt a lot

Answer (score 0):

There is also `hg incoming` (alias `hg in`; additionally `hg outgoing`/`hg out`) which can be used *before* pulling which will show you the revisions which will be pulled. At times this can be useful.