# Mercurial: info on modified files

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Before pulling from the central repositiry, I usually use the 'hg incoming' command to see what I will be pulling. However, this only gives me a list of changesets with some comments, and not a list of the actual files that have been modified.

1) In such a situation, how can I get a list of modified files (including some basic info about the chane, like Removed, Moved, etc)?

2) Similarly, when I do an 'hg status', I get the differences between my local working copy and what is currently on the repository. However, a more useful feature would be to get the differences between what is incoming and my local working copy. How can I get this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a recent enough version for `--stat`, you can get a similar overview using `status`:

```
cd repo

// grab the newest changes into a bundle
hg incoming --bundle morechanges.bun

// get an id for the current tip
hg tip
  changeset: x:abcdef
  ...

// see what's changed by overlaying the bundle on the repo
hg -R morechanges.bun status --rev abcdef:tip
  //info you're looking for

// everything's good; add the bundle to the repo
hg pull morechanges.bun

rm morechanges.bun
```

Answer (score 3):

1/ Most options are presented in "[how to see files in repository before running 'update'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271274/how-to-see-files-in-repository-before-running-update/4272944#4272944)":

```
hg incoming --stat
```

Notes:

> - For remote repository, using `--bundle` avoids downloading the changesets twice if the incoming is followed by a pull.
> - `--stat`: output diffstat-style summary of changes.
>     (ie: Statistics of changes with the following format: "modified files: +added/-removed lines")

2/ See [RDiff extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RdiffExtension) (and the SO question "[Using Mercurial, is there an easy way to diff my working copy with the tip file in the default remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156280/using-mercurial-is-there-an-easy-way-to-diff-my-working-copy-with-the-tip-file-i)")

Comment: The --stat option is not recognized by my version of Mercurial. Is this option available from the native product or does it require any add-ons? Thanks.

Comment: @elesser: no it should be a native command. Its may be linked to Hg1.6: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/WhatsNew#A1.6_.282010-07-01.29 from last July: see this patch http://www.selenic.com/pipermail/mercurial-devel/2010-April/020816.html (which is about `log`, but also `incoming` options)